# array_push in codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

Controller

```
public $mainstack = array(
    'applet' => "Flow"
);

function pushflow($data)
{       
    array_push($this->mainstack, $data);
    avb_print_r($this->mainstack);
}

public function save_dial()
{
    $data = array(
        'applet' => "Dial",
        'dial_whom' => $this->input->post('selecteddialnum'),
        'selected_caller' => $this->input->post('scaller'),
        'selected_whisper' => $this->input->post('swhisper'),
    );
    $this->pushflow($data);
}
```

Every time the function `save_dial` runs, it creates a new array and pushes the array `$data` into it. What I want to do is every time I run `save_dial` it would just push the new array into the existing array `$mainstack` instead of pushing it into a new array. Can anyone please help me here?

values being printed using array_push

```
Array
(
    [applet] => Flow
    [0] => Array
        (
          //data
        )

)
```

```
Array
(
    [applet] => Flow
    [0] => Array
        (
          //data
        )

)
```

I would like it to print

`

```
Array
(
    [applet] => Flow
    [0] => Array
        (
          //data
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
          //data
        )
```

)

Answer (score 0):

You are adding an array inside your `$mainstack` array when you use `array_push()`. The result will look something like:

```
'applet' => "Flow",
0 => $data,  // contents of $data the first time $data was added
1 => $data   // contents of $data the second time $data was added
// etc.
```

You probably want something like a [union](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php) (or a merge) instead:

```
function pushflow($data)
{
    # Use $data elements where duplicate keys exist
    $this->mainstack =  $data + $this->mainstack;
    avb_print_r($this->mainstack);
}
```

Now your `$data` array will be added to the original array and existing key/values will be replaced with the values from `$data`.

Comment: sorry for the late response, `$data + $this->mainstack;` is not working it as should be, i have edited the question to show the values being returned by the print_r

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick (use [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.array-merge.php) instead of [array_push](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.array-push.php)):

```
function pushflow($data)
{       
    $this->mainstack = array_merge($this->mainstack, $data);
    avb_print_r($this->mainstack);
}
```

What `array_push` does is, it adds a new element (or multiple) to the existing array, so if your element is an array you end up having a multidimensional array. If you would still use `array_push` though, you have to either iterate through $data, and push each element one by one, or modify `save_dial()` method to call `pushflow()` for each element you want to add, instead of adding it to `$data`.

> UPDATE

Please observe the following code:

```
class SimpleClass
{
public $mainstack = array(
    'applet' => "Flow"
);

function pushflow($data)
{       
    $this->mainstack = array_merge($this->mainstack, $data);
    echo '<pre>' . print_r($this->mainstack, true) . '</pre>';
}

public function save_dial()
{
    $data = array(
        'applet' => "Dial",
        'dial_whom' => 'selecteddialnum',
        'selected_caller' => 'scaller',
        'selected_whisper' => 'swhisper'
    );
    $this->pushflow($data);
}
}
$a = new SimpleClass();
$a->save_dial();
```

, will produce this result:

```
Array
(
    [applet] => Dial
    [dial_whom] => selecteddialnum
    [selected_caller] => scaller
    [selected_whisper] => swhisper
)
```

If it is not the format you intend to obtain, please make clear with an example.

Comment: sorry for the late response, array merge is not working it as should be, i have edited the question to show the values being returned by the print_r